# Encode axis aligned unit vector in a single float value

Tags: opengl, glsl, webgl

I want to encode axis-aligned unit vector in a single float value. Like this:

0: vec3(0, 0 ,0)

1: vec3(1, 0, 0)

2: vec3(0, 1, 0)

3: vec3(0, 0, 1)

To convert float to vector according to the table I can write a simple code

```
in float axisIndex
...
vec3 axis = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
if (axisIndex > 0.5) {
  axis = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
if (axisIndex > 1.5) {
  axis = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
}
if (axisIndex > 2.5) {
  axis = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

However if branches are slow. Is there a **fast** way to convert a float into vector without using if branches and external buffers, just using math?

Comment: Why? Why not just use signed bytes. That will give you 3 bytes per normal which is one less than 1 float per normal. And if you only want axis aligned normals you should be able to do it with a single byte.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and twgl library as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must do things this way, then the best way is with a simple array index:

```
in uint axisIndex;

const vec3[4] table = {
  vec3(0, 0 ,0), 
  vec3(1, 0, 0),
  vec3(0, 1, 0),
  vec3(0, 0, 1)
};
```

Then just use `table[axisIndex]` to fetch the value. You can provide integer values to a shader using `glVertexAttribIPointer`. While you could use an unsigned byte for the type you provide, it's better to just go for an unsigned int; OpenGL implementations don't like vertex attributes that aren't 4-byte aligned.

That being said, this is really unnecessary. You could just pass 3 [normalized, signed bytes](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Normalized_Integer) as the attribute, rather than a single index. It won't take up any more space in your vertex data (since again, implementations don't like misaligned attributes), and it probably won't be slower to process.

Answer (score 1):

A fast way would be

```
axis = vec3(float(axisIndex == 1.0), float(axisIndex == 2.0), float(axisIndex == 3.0))
```

Note that axisIndex could be a `uint` rather than a `float`, in which case you need to pass only 1 byte per vertex to your GPU if you pass it as `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.